# Why my stored procedures in MariaDB do not appear when connect to Tableau?

Tags: stored-procedures, mariadb, tableau-desktop, heidisql

I don't know why but I can not see the stored procedures appear when I connect the database to Tableau (I use MariaDB). I can only see the data tables.

Anyone has the same problems with me? I am a newbie so I am not sure if my description is clear or not.

Use the stored procedures.

Comment: Looks like tableau does not support `MySQL` stored procedures, so is likely the same for `MariaDB` as well. See the [top answer here](https://community.tableau.com/s/question/0D54T00000C6WYJSA3/can-i-connect-mysql-stored-procedures-from-tableau-dekstop-) ... which claims: `Stored procedures are currently only supported for Sybase ASE, SQL Server, and Teradata`

Comment: I have the same issue and I looking for solutions

Answer (score 0):

I found that Tableau does not connect to stored processes and that one way around this is that when you connect to your server, you should use the initial query function. Once you log in, grab Custom SQL and for that script simply use

```
select * from #nameoftemptable
```

and Execute.